# Doing a practice grabbing info from a file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So i am new to matplotlib and i was using a youtube video and the recreate its code and see if that works for me. The code is below,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[]
y=[]
readFile = open('attempt2.txt', 'r')
sepFile= readFile.read().split('/n')
readFile.close()

for batman in sepFile:
    xAndy = batman.split(',')
    x.append(int(xAndy[0]))
    y.append(int(xAndy[1]))

print x
print y

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('attempt 2')
plt.xlabel('attempt 2 x')
plt.ylabel('attempt 2 y')

plt.show()
```

When i run this code,the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "attempt_2.py", line 13, in <module>
y.append(int(xAndy[1]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5\n2'
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong and what this error means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare these scraps from your code: `split('/n')` and from the error: `'5\n2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out what was happening, there were some empty lines at the end of the data and i just had to make a modification to the len of the xAndY

```
for plotpair in sepFile:
xandy = plotpair.split(',')
if len(xandy)>1:
    x.append(int(float(xandy[0])))
    y.append(int(float(xandy[1])))
```

This took care of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You made the very easily-overlooked error of mistaking the `\` and `/` characters. The file-reading line should look like `sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')`, as it is `\n` and not `/n` that ends a line.